# React-Native pass data from Java from notification

Tags: java, android, react-native

I have a an Android service that emits notifications at certain intervals. I need the user to navigate to a certain page after he clicks the notification.

This is the configuration I use. This does open the app, but I can't figure out how to post the data to React-Native.

```
Bundle b = new Bundle();
b.putString("MyNameBundle", "Please Work");

final NotificationCompat.Builder builder =
                    new NotificationCompat.Builder(this).
                      setContentTitle("Sample Title").
                      setContentText("SampleText").
                      setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.notify);
                      setExtras(b);

Intent testIntent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
testIntent.putExtras(b);

PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, testIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
builder.setContentIntent(contentIntent);

final NotificationManager nManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
```

I would prefer to not use external libraries.

Comment: I'm having a problem too.. :(

Comment: Does anyone find a solution?